# In the SE Android App, upvoted comments are not able to be un-upvoted

Tags: bug, comments, android-app

In the SE Android app, when I've upvoted a comment through the web interface, the tab for actions still shows up, and I have the option to upvote the comment when I click it. I can't un-upvote the comment from here though, so I shouldn't be able to click the tab at all.

Comment: I am currently able to undo upvoted comment on Android. Version of Android and Device? Repro steps would help.